# I want HTML content from the script. using requests and Bs4 library

Tags: json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I  am trying to scrape some data from Twitter, but I am getting data in the form of a script, please help me to solve this issue, I want HTML content from the script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from requests import get

def data(i):
    page='https://twitter.com/search?q=%23{}&src=typeahead_click'
    page1=page.format(i)
    #print(page)
    load=get(page1)
    data=bs4(load.text,'html.parser')
    print(data)

    
i='JobseekersSA'
data(i)
```

The result I got is in the script, please help me to get the contents of html.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Twitter now requires JavaScript. While there may be a way to get the data as JSON, there is no way to get it as HTML without having JavaScript or some other script convert that data to HTML. The data you scrape will likely be JSON. I would use the inspector and other webtools of a modern browser to see what all is being fetched, look for data files, and where they are in relation to the original page.